# Calculating Resources For Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I want to create a Kubernetes cluster in my on-prem storage server.

I was looking for a way to calculate how much CPU, Memory and storage I need in order to create a minimal Kubernetes cluster and how to calculate for increasing them in the future.

At least for now, I want to create a cluster to include at least 3 worker nodes in addition to the needed nodes for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what tool you are going to use to install k8s on your environment. There are many tools installing k8s and each tool has their own minimal hardware requirement.

This is one example.

`Kubeadm installation guide` : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

```
* Hardware minimal requirement for 1 node

2 GB or more of RAM per machine (any less will leave little room for your apps).
2 CPUs or more.
```